# How are Subscriber ID's handled with the Contact Deletion feature?

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

In SFMC, each subscriber is assigned by the system a unique ID called the Subscriber ID. I've never really paid much attention to this field, but with the [GA360 integration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_utm_parameters.htm&type=5) this field becomes the unique subscriber identifier for matching records with their Google Client ID.

It appears that subscriber ID's are numbers raised in sequential value. Does anybody know if:

- When a contact is deleted, then re-added into the system, will they be assigned a new Subscriber ID or will it somehow re-pair them with their previous one?
- If they don't receive the same Subscriber ID as before the deletion, are Subscriber ID's ever re-assigned, or will they always be unique (even across deleted contacts)?

Bonus points if this is documented anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once a contact is deleted, the SubscriberID is gone forever. When you create the same contact again, they'll be assigned a new SubscriberID.

SubscriberIDs don't recycle.